# tkzMarkAngles small angle cause "Dimension too large" error

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

This example works fine with the angle greater than 5 degree, but if it's less than 5 degree, compile will fail.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\angle{5}
\def\r{2cm}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (\angle:\r);
\coordinate (B) at (0:\r);
\foreach \x/\y in {O/A,O/B} {
    \draw (\x) -- (\y);
} 
%\tkzMarkAngles(A,O,B);
\tkzMarkAngles(B,O,A);
\foreach \x in {O,A,B} {
    \node [circle,fill=red,minimum size=1pt,inner sep=0,label=below:{$\x$}] at (\x) {};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I know too small angle is meaning less to call \tkzMarkAngles, but it cost much time to debug when I try to create a animation, which will change the angle dynamically.

error message:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
! Dimension too large.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.15 \tkzMarkAngles(B,O,A)
                          ;
? x
No pages of output.
```

The error message (Dimension too large) confuse me also! why it's too large, it should be too small :-).

Answer (score 2):

A solution ! Several possibilities : A new veclen command like in the example below with the help of the package xfp or with the help of lua. I use "decoration" in the macro `\tkzMarkAngles`and this library has a problem with "veclen" for small values.
Another possibility is to scale (4) the picture.
I use this version of "veclen" in the new version of tkz-euclide v2.42
[here](http://altermundus.fr/files/euclide/geom_2.42b.zip)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,xfp}
\usetkzobj{all}
\makeatletter
\let\pgfmath@function@veclen\relax
\pgfmathdeclarefunction*{veclen}{2}{%
\begingroup%
    \pgfmath@x#1pt\relax%
    \pgfmath@y#2pt\relax%
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \edef\tkz@temp@a{\fpeval{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgf@xa}}}
    \edef\tkz@temp@b{\fpeval{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgf@ya}}}
    \edef\tkz@temp@sum{\fpeval{%
        (\tkz@temp@a*\tkz@temp@a+\tkz@temp@b*\tkz@temp@b)}}
    \edef\tkz@xfpMathLen{\fpeval{sqrt(\tkz@temp@sum)}}
%\edef\pgfmath@tmp{\fpeval{round(\tkzFPMathLen,6)}}
%\pgfmath@tmp %
    \pgfmath@returnone\tkz@xfpMathLen pt%
\endgroup%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.75]
\def\angle{5}
\def\r{2cm}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (\angle:\r);
\coordinate (B) at (0:\r);
\foreach \x/\y in {O/A,O/B} {
    \draw (\x) -- (\y);
} 
%\tkzMarkAngles(A,O,B);
\tkzMarkAngles(B,O,A);
\foreach \x in {O,A,B} {
    \node [circle,fill=red,minimum size=1pt,inner sep=0,label=below:{$\x$}] at (\x) {};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For annotation purpose, more simple solution as below:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc,angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\angle{5}
\def\r{2cm}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (\angle:\r);
\coordinate (B) at (0:\r);
\foreach \x/\y in {O/A,O/B} {
    \draw (\x) -- (\y);
} 
\pic [draw] {angle = B--O--A};
\foreach \x in {O,A,B} {
    \node [circle,fill=red,minimum size=1pt,inner sep=0,label=below:{$\x$}] at (\x) {};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\angle{30}
\def\r{2cm}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (\angle:\r);
\coordinate (B) at (0:\r);
\foreach \x/\y in {O/A,O/B} {
    \draw (\x) -- (\y);
} 
\pic [draw,"$\theta$",angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = B--O--A};
\foreach \x in {O,A,B} {
    \node [circle,fill=red,minimum size=1pt,inner sep=0,label=below:{$\x$}] at (\x) {};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: No it's not the solution. The problem is not to draw an arc but to use the option `decorate` to add a mark on the arc